# How do I find the line of C++ which locks a Linux futex?

Tags: c++, linux, futex

I've got a performance problem with a large application written in C++. The program uses only 150% CPU, while the server is a 24-core hyperthreaded EPYC and other, similar applications can reliably hit the expected 4800% CPU load. `iotop` shows virtually no I/O, which is expected.

As the program is apparently neither I/O-bound nor CPU-bound, I checked `strace` and found that the vast majority of traced calls are waits on a single `futex`. That is to say: 48 of the 50 threads in the program appear to lock the same futex, which explains quite well why the CPU load only barely exceeds 100%.

Example:

```
[pid 11581] futex(0x55acec47a900, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 11580] futex(0x55acec47a900, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 11579] futex(0x55acec47a900, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 11578] futex(0x55acec47a900, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 11577] futex(0x55acec47a900, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 11576] futex(0x55acec47a900, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
```

Now the problem for me is: how do I find the offending code? The program is not deadlocks, just slow, so the usual techniques to find deadlocks do not work.

Comment: Connect a debugger during execution, randomly pause the execution and inspect calltrace?

Comment: @KamilCuk: I think I got lucky with that one, yes. It cost me quite a bit of time, so that's why I self-answered it. I'd be happy to accept a better answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way I found myself was to run the program in GDB. Since most threads are blocked, `info threads` will show most of the threads in the same state. For me, that happened to be blocked in `__lll_lock_wait`. Switching to any of these threads gave me a stacktrace showing how I ended up in `__lll_lock_wait`. Three levels up the stack I found my offending code.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I find the line of C++ which locks a Linux futex?

If you accept to *change* your C++ source code, you might compile it with `g++ -O -g` (so with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debugging information) using a *recent* [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler and use Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace). That library gives nice backtracing information at runtime using DWARF debug info in your [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) and [shared libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Then you could either subclass the [locking C++ classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) (e.g. `std::mutex` or `std::lock_guard`) or add extra C++ code (perhaps with [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) [X-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)) to use that backtracking library.

Also consider a profiling approach with [GNU gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/).

Another possible approach (worthwhile only for a large code base of more than a hundred thousand lines of C++) might be to use dynamic linker tricks (e.g. `LD_PRELOAD`, see [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)) to redefine your C++ standard library, or to write your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to modify the emitted code related to [futex(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html) or to [locking C++ classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

For a small code base, consider also writing your specialized [metaprogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) (in the spirit of [Qt moc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html)) to transform your C++ code (e.g. to automatically add C++ calls to `libbacktrace` functions) then update your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) (e.g. your `Makefile`) to use it.

For a concrete example, look into the source code of GCC

#### Be however aware that deadlock or synchronization related bugs are typical [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

So budget several weeks of debugging efforts.